# Geodjango model combined with non geo model

Tags: json, django, geodjango

I am a django beginner and trying to programm a simple geo application.
My setup: django/geodjango + leaflet. Everything works fine and geo objects (GeoObject) are displayed. But now I want to add aditional properties ("status") from another model and display them also via leaflet - but I´m stuck.

my models.py:

```
class GeoObject(models.Model):                                     
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="name", max_length=20)
    location = models.PointField(srid=4326)                    
 
class Status(models.Model):
    geoobject = models.OneToOneField(GeoObject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, default=0, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(verbose_name="Sensor", max_length=20)
```

my views.py:

```
def GeoMapView(request): #view to display leaflet map with geo objects     
    q=Sensor.objects.all()
    context = {'q':q}
    return render(request, 'xitylytix_sensors/sensor_map.html', context)

def GeoData(request): #sending geo data                                                             
    q=GeoObject.objects.all()
    geo_data = serialize('geojson', q)
    return HttpResponse(geo_data, content_type='json')
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('geomap/', views.GeoMapView, name='geo_map'), #display via template/leaflet map
    path('geodata/', views.GeoData, name='geo_data'), #sending geo data
]
```

json data:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "EPSG:4326"}}, "features": [{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"name": "001", "pk": "1"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [8.849315642079313, 50.07892796957105]}}, ...
```

I tried with one to one relation (see model), but "status" in the json file is missing in "properties". Does anyone have an idea?

What I am also tried:

What I want is this, but its not working, just retriving objects without GeoObject data:

```
q = Status.objects.all().only('status','geoobject__name', 'geoobject__location',)
```

Query is working, but I am retrieving only list of dicts, what I can not use to serialize:

```
q = Status.objects.all().values('status','geoobject__name', 'geoobject__location',)
```

Comment: you could serialize your objects without any filter and access expected object with Javascript in frontend. This method decrease server side process and increase speed.
When you use value method in backend, serialize won't work.
If you insist to do that just use (for item in queryset) method and save all you need in an object. (iterate over quryset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found a solution which is working for me:

views.py:

```
def createleafletobject(q):
    queryset  = []

    for element in table:
        LeafObj = LeafletObject(
            name = element['name'],
            location = element['location'],
            geoobject = element['geoobject'],
            status = element['status],
        ) 
        queryset.append(LeafObj)
    return queryset 

def GeoMapView(request): #view to display leaflet map with geo objects     
    q=Sensor.objects.all()
    context = {'q':q}
    return render(request, 'xitylytix_sensors/sensor_map.html', context)

def GeoData(request): #sending geo data                                                             
    q = Status.objects.all().values('geoobject__name', 'geoobject__location', 'geoobject', 'status')
    q = createleafletobject(q)
    geo_data = serialize('geojson', q)
    return HttpResponse(geo_data, content_type='json')
```

So what I am doing is to query data form two object via "values()", receiving and dictionary and transforming with my self written "createleafletobject(table)" class into an object, which I am szerializing and passing to leaflet.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to do that? You can simply create object in views and add data to your GeoObject model.just add data column to your database and after that in views you can add specific data to your model.

```
def GeoData(request):                                                            
    q=GeoObject.objects.all()
for item in queryset:
          GeoObject.objects.create(
                something = item.queryset(data)
                      )
    geo_data = serialize('geojson', q)
    return HttpResponse(geo_data, content_type='json')
```

And if you want to access data in another model, you should use foreign key.

Comment: Thank u very much for your answer. But I am not realy understand what your code is doing. As I understand with .create() method u are writing in the database - I dont what that.

What I want is this, but its not working, just retriving objects without GeoObject data:
q = Status.objects.all().only('status','geoobject__name', 'geoobject__location',)

Query is working, but I am retrieving only list of dicts, what I can not use to serialize:
q = Status.objects.all().values('status','geoobject__name', 'geoobject__location',)